# How to remove header "accept-encoding:gzip" with okhttp

Tags: java, android, okhttp

I am using OkHttp 3 and trying to remove `accept-encoding` header completely from requests made by `OkHttpClient`.

I use `.removeHeader("accept-encoding")` on the `Request` object, but the header still appears in the request.

Is there a way to remove the header completely and not just replace it with a different value?

Comment: Have you ever succeed in this? I'm trying same with  okhttp v5.0.0-alpha.10. None of suggested solutions work: I can only replace the header. There is no way to remove it. Btw I have a multipart request (json + jpeg), and my server expects request w/o accept-encoding header whatsoever.

Comment: @sinek *"my server expects request w/o accept-encoding header"* What happens when the header is present?

Comment: it fails with 500 status code

Comment: @sinek Do you have access to the code on the server? I see no reason why you would get a 500 error.

Comment: @sinek I tested the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60984097/21144042) with `5.0.0-alpha.11` and it works...

Comment: @DiegoBorba unfortunately, not woking for me. Before request I don't see any headers (and I don't set any), but after it has completed, I do see accept-encoding attached.

Comment: @sinek I think you need to ask another question and put an [MCvE] that we can run.

Comment: @DiegoBorba We were able to fix the problem on the server side at the end, thus no longe in need to remove the header.

Answer (score 4):

You can remove it using a network interceptor.

```
final class AcceptEncodingInterceptor implements Interceptor {
  @Override public Response intercept(Interceptor.Chain chain) throws IOException {
    Request request = chain.request();
        .newBuilder()
        .removeHeader("Accept-Encoding")
        .build();
    return chain.proceed(request);
  }
}
```

The the interceptor like this:

```
new OkHttpClient.Builder()
    ...
    .addNetworkInterceptor(new AcceptEncodingInterceptor())
    .build();
```

Note that is has to be `addNetworkInterceptor`, simply `addInterceptor` does not work.

Comment: This does not seem to work. The header remains..

Comment: Where are you seeing it?

Comment: `addNetworkInterceptor` works for me.

Comment: Doesn't work on  v5.0.0-alpha.10 (I have multipart request where I basically need "curl -vv -X POST "https://endpoint/blah" \-H 'Content-type:multipart/form-data' \-F 'data={ ... };type=application/json' \-F 'image=@image.jpg;type=image/jpeg'" request in Android.)

Comment: What do you mean by "has to be `addNetworkInterceptor`, simply `addNetworkInterceptor` does not work"?

Comment: @user207421 It's a typo (I've corrected it now), you need to use `addNetworkInterceptor` and it should work